# Need to implement the Python itertools function "chain" in a class

Tags: python, class, python-itertools, chain

I am trying to emulate the "chain" function in itertools in python.

I came up with the following generator.

```
# Chain make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable
# until it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all
# of the iterables are exhausted.
def chain_for(*a) :
    if a :
       for i in a :
          for j in i :
             yield j
    else :
       pass
```

How can I emulate the same function in a class? 
Since the input to the function is an arbitrary number of lists, I am not sure if packing/unpacking can be used in classes, and if so I am not sure how to unpack in the '**init**' method.

```
class chain_for :
   def __init__(self, ...) :
      ....
   def __iter__(self) :
      self
   def __next__(self) :
      .....
```

Thank you.

Comment: "I am not sure if packing/unpacking is useful when using classes" I'm not sure how the location of using packing/unpacking affects its usefulness

Comment: I meant if it can be used in classes. Updated the question.

Comment: yes, it can....

Comment: How? any suggestions or reference?

Comment: There is not (much) difference between `def chain_for(*a):`  and `def __init__(self, *a):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not (much) difference between `def chain_for(*a):` and `def __init__(self, *a):`.
Hence, a very crude way to implement this can be:

```
class chain_for:
    def __init__(self, *lists):
        self.lists = iter(lists)
        self.c = iter(next(self.lists))

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            try:
                yield next(self.c)
            except StopIteration:
                try:
                    self.c = iter(next(self.lists))
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                yield next(self.c)

chain = chain_for([1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6])
print(list(chain))
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I see three major flaws here. First, this fails to be either an iterator or a reusable iterable. [Second, it breaks if any of the inputs are empty.](https://ideone.com/2ZksOS) Third, using `yield` defeats what little point there is in writing a class - almost the only reason to write a class for this kind of thing is as a learning exercise in how to manage iterator state manually.

Comment: @user2357112 `"almost the only reason to write a class for this kind of thing is as a learning exercise in how to manage iterator state manually"` Which is obviously the premise of this question, otherwise why would anyone attempt to re-implement a well tested stdlib code. The other 2 points of your comment are exactly why I used the phrase "a very crude way" in my answer

Comment: Then why did you use `yield`?

Comment: @user2357112 because I felt like? why does it matter? You are welcome to post an answer which does not use `yield`.  I've never said using `yield` was the only/most correct way to answer this question.

Comment: If you're using `yield`, you're *not* managing iterator state manually. You're letting the generator suspension mechanism do it for you. This defeats what you just said was obviously the point of the question.

Comment: Thanks again, @DeepSpace for providing the solution.